# How to implement paging library with realm in android?

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform, android-paging-library

Is there any better way to implement paging library with the realm in android? I found Monarchy wrapper, but is there any better way?

Comment: Realm developers already answered this question on their github : https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2367

Comment: Monarchy wrapper does what needs to be done in order to expose RealmResults from a background looper thread with changes but paged. Technically it could be done even without Monarchy library, but then you'd have to do the same thing Monarchy does.

Answer (score 1):

Little late on this one, but maybe someone will find it useful:
Since Realm has Lazy Loading, just getting data from realm is not the problem. If you want to load huge amount of realm data into RecyclerView for example you can get all Realm objects as List and pass new List<T.subList(fromIndex, toIndex)>. You can combine this approach with infinite scroll for example. In this way you can ignore Monarchy.

Comment: "just getting data from realm is not the problem" Except if you are "getting" the data from a different thread.